# Why can't the shell script file execute.Linux told me the file of no existing

Tags: linux, shell, centos

I typed the command:./case-7.sh

I can't execute the shell script file.The Linux told me (-bash: ./case-7.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: haven't that file or directory)

I make sure that it exists in the path and it has executable permission.

Why the Centos told me that? Please tell me what I should do?Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tries given the rights to your file with `chmod +x case-7.sh` ? 
What interpreters do you have on your computer ? Maybe trying launching with `/bin/bash case-7.sh` could solve the problem ? 
If not, add the code of your .sh file so that we can help you more precisely

Comment: Thank you!  Your anwser very good. I have found the problem.Because my editor add an invisible character.